# Illegal start of expression (nested methods)

Tags: java

I get Illegal Start of Expression as below as:

```
Test.java:70: illegal start of expression
  public void sample(){
  ^
Test.java:70: illegal start of expression
  public void sample(){
         ^
Test.java:70: ';' expected
  public void sample(){
                    ^
3 errors
```

Here is Code:

```
import java.text.*;

import java.util.*;

public class Test {

    public static void main(String args[]) {

        public void sample(){

            System.out.println("Hello Working ....");

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Java doesn't support methods nested within one another (and you're also missing a closing bracket for the class).

Comment: As per the @KonstantinYovkov comment it java doesn't support. to make this program working create a method outside main and call it in main method

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the code below:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        sample();
    }

    private static void sample() {
        System.out.println("Hello Working ....");
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Hello Working ....
```

Answer (score 1):

Java does not allow to create methods within a method. This is a general rule

Instead to make this program working

Try this way:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Test test = new Test();
        test.sample();
    }

    public void sample() {

        System.out.println("Hello Working ....");

    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try it this way:

```
import java.text.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

  public static void main(String args[]) {
     System.out.println("Hello Working ....");
  }

  public void sample(){ 
  }
}
```