# Illegal start of expression with method declaration

Tags: java

Compiling this simple code using javac, it gives me the following error

> Test3.java:38: error: illegal start of expression
>
> public static int minFun (int a, int b) {

I tried declaring the variables outside the main (i.e. public static int a, b, c) but nothing changed.

It baffles me since I was following [this tutorial](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_methods.htm) with a very similar example code that worked.

Thanks in advance for any help.

```
  // Program to output the minimum of two integer numbers

  import java.io.*;

  public class Test3 {

  public static void main (String args[]) {

          int a, b, c;
          String rA, rB;

          InputStreamReader input = new InputStreamReader (System.in);
          BufferedReader keyboard = new BufferedReader (input);

          System.out.println ("Please, enter two integer numbers.");
          try {
                  rA = keyboard.readLine ();
                  a = Integer.parseInt (rA);
                  rB = keyboard.readLine ();
                  b = Integer.parseInt (rB);
          }
          catch (IOException e) {
                  System.err.println ("Not a proper integer number.");
          }
          catch (NumberFormatException e) {
                  System.err.println ("Not a proper integer number.");
          }

          c = minFun (a, b);

          if (a != b) {
                  System.out.println ("The smaller number is " + c);
          }
          else {
                  System.out.println ("The two numbers are equals.");
  }

  public static int minFun (int a, int b) {

          int min;

          if (a < b) {
                  min = a;
          }
          else {
                  min = b;
          }
          return min;
  }
  }
```

Comment: A closing curly bracket is missing at the last else of main.

Comment: The last curly bracket before your method signature is the one that closes the `else` block and not the `main` method. Add one after it...

Comment: Ffs it was something that simple, sorry for wasting y'all time

Comment: And to follow up on those two comments: the reason that's a problem is that without that curly brace, the un-indented curly brace after the `else` just closes that `else` clause -- but keeps you within the `main` function. That means that `public static int minFunction` is a line within that `main` function, which isn't allowed. You can't define a function inside another function in Java.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Illegal start of expression (nested methods)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34876551/illegal-start-of-expression-nested-methods)

Comment: Thank you for reminding me to check the answer, done.
Also thanks @yshavit for the insight

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
      if (a != b) {
              System.out.println ("The smaller number is " + c);
      }
      else {
              System.out.println ("The two numbers are equals.");
      } // <----- was not present
```

**This line here is missing a curly brace.**

Comment: The goal of Stack Overflow is to create a library of questions and answers that everyone can benefit from. Questions that are due to typographical errors are very unlikely to help anyone else. That is why they should be closed as such, instead of answered. (And they generally get deleted after a while so answering them would be a waste of time in the first place.)

Comment: True that. The answer is still valid though (up-voting the answer, voting to close the question).